# get the tableview section index when tapped on textfield

Tags: ios

I have developed a custom tableView that contains a text field.
 When I tap on the textfiled I am receiving the created `indexPath.section`, but I need the current `indexpath.section` of the selected textfiled. How can I get the table view section index of the selected text field?

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

 return 18;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

   [self.tableview setSectionIndexColor:UIColor.redColor];
   UITableViewCell *cell=[[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:nil];
   sectionTag = indexPath.section;
  if (cell!=nil) {}
  return cell;
}
```

I have called sectionTag to get the section of table view, but I am receiving the new created section index

Comment: Does your tableView has multiple sections ? Why you need multiple sections instead of multiple rows ?

Comment: from where you are adding your textfield to the section? Can you share few more lines of code please